# Stop flipping with emilsjolander FlipView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-view

in my application I have a flipView using the emilsjolander library. It's great, but I can't stop automatically the flipping effect when I open the FlipView. Infact, if I touch the screen the effect stop, but I would stop it after some seconds. Do you know if the library contain a method for it or, alternatively, for simulate the touchEvent after some seconds?
Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the answer is so late but it will help others if they stuck in that issue. You can disable automatic flipping on first page by just commenting:

```
 //peakNext(false);
```

Comment: thanks anyway but I solved modifying the library similarly your response

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyFlipView extends se.emilsjolander.flipview.FlipView
{
    private boolean isEnabled = true;

    public MyFlipView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

    }

    public MyFlipView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyFlipView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        if (isEnabled)
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void disable()
    {
        isEnabled = false;
    }

    public void enable()
    {
        isEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Declare xml as 
<"YourPackage".MyFlipView

/>